# Short story about an alien tortured to get information that happens to be the proof of something amazing

Tags: story-identification

I have little information to share, apart from the striking ending (spoiler alert).
It's a short story about the interaction of humans with an alien race.
AFAIR, the aliens are good aliens and are helping humans in some way, but for some reason one or more of the aliens are being held captive and tortured to extract information about some 'power' they have.

It turns out that 'power' or trait is proof of the existence of something humans have always wondered about.

What I remember clearly is the ending. One of the torturers (or a witness of the torture) asks the exhausted alien why they resisted so much to tell the humans such a wonderful thing: that there is something that answers an existential question that has puzzled humanity for ages. And the last line is the half-dying alien's answer:

SPOILER

> "*You don't have it*."

I have read this story in some collection of short stories in the early 90s. The collections might have been Hugo or Nebula awards of the past, dating back to the 60s or 70s. The alien could have been 'angel-like' in their appearance, but I am not sure about that, maybe they had wings or just feathers.

Comment: @JayFor YES! That's it
 Less than five minutes after asking the question. You guys never disappoint, unlike the search engine. I think we can we tag this question as duplicate.